# C++ User-defined 2 dimensional array with geometrical progression

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, user-input, visual-studio-2013

I am learning C++ by myself,by solving different problems. 
I am trying to solve problem which was originally designed for Pascal in C++.
It should ask user to input 3 integers M,N and q. 
Then it should make 2d array of integers with size MxN, where all the elements of (I=I,...M) line will be the members of geometrical progression with first element equal to number of line (I) and denominator q.

I wanted to create a dynamic massive, but I realized that it won't really work with two undefined integers. So, I tried vectors. I guess that I created them in a right way, but I've got no idea how to make a geometrical progression.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m, n, q;

    cout << "Enter the number for M \n";
    cin >> m;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "This is not a number! " << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Enter the  number for N \n";
    cin >> n;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "This is not a number! " << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Enter the number  for Q \n";
    cin >> q;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "This is not a number! " << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    int** matrix;
    matrix = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[n];


    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        matrix[i][0] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = (i + 1)*pow(i, j);
            cout << matrix[i][j];

        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You can create a two dimensional array of a variable size, although it involves memory allocation and is slightly ugly.

```
int** matrix;
matrix = new int*[M];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[N];
```

That's the code to create an array of size MxN.
Don't forget to deallocate your memory like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    delete matrix[i];
delete matrix;
```

As far as your question about the geometric progression, I am unsure of what you are asking. When you say geometric progression do you refer to something along the lines of `2 10 50 250` etc.? I am not sure what you mean by "lines" as you don't refer to any such variable in your code.

*EDIT*

So once the MxN matrix is created, iterate through the rows and initialize the rows like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    matrix[i][0] = i+1;
}
```

This should set the first column of each row to the correct number.
Then something along the lines of this should fill out the rest of the geometric progression:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = (i+1)*pow(r,j); 
        //note that you'll probably have to do some typecasting
        //p.s. I'm not 100% sure that this is the correct formula
    }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know if it works because I haven't tested it myself.

Print the matrix like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I guess that line is line of the matrix, for example it should look like this. If it's 3x3 matrix.                             {1 3 6}                                                                    {2 6 12} {3 12 24} That's how i think it is.

Comment: So for example, matrix[0][0] would start with 0, matrix[1][0] would start with one?

Comment: yes, 1st number in the line represent the line number. then every number starting from second one is made from previous number times q.  So it's like [1 1q 1q*q]

Comment: I am trying to print the results in a correct way. Right now I got some long numbers, not geometric sequence.

Comment: Please post the code you are using. I can't help you without seeing what the problem is. As to the "long numbers", it sounds like you are accessing elements of the array that have yet to be initialized.

Comment: I just added the whole thing to my initial post. I am think that I am lost somewhere.

Comment: Declare whatever your geometric progression denominator is as a float, eg. `float q;`. Where you have `pow(i,j)` it should be `pow(q,j)`. Note that you must `include <cmath>` for this function. Pow takes the first argument and raises it to the second argument. Also I would print after all the values have been initialized, not during the loop.